# How to set up Apache mod_rewrite redirect rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I am not quite familiar with Apache settings. I need to make website loading sub-directory content except one page.

Currently got a website and need to make all calls to http://www.domain.com & http://domain.com load contents from http://www.domain.com/subfolder (but looks like http://www.domain.com)

Only except the http://www.domain.com/checkout page, this one page should redirect to https://www.domain.com/checkout for secure checkout

The current mod_rewrite shown as below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ domain/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domain%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* domain/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* domain/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.au/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.au$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.au/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.au$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://www.domain.com.au [R,NC]
```

Comment: Please post your current rewrite rules.

Comment: Please do not add 'urgent' and 'am waiting online' to questions here. Volunteers tend to answer questions at their leisure `:)` and in any case, questions here are best if they are written for a future audience - for whom the OPs urgency isn't helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file named `.htaccess` in the root of your webserver and add following lines of code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^checkout/(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/checkout/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

rewrite for your complete .htaccess-file (check if this works, then I'll delete the previous code):

```
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://www.yourdomain.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^checkout/(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/checkout/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*) /subfolder/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your promote reply Dave! But It seems not working, I tried to type www.domain.com in the browser, got "Internal Server Error", any thoughts?

Comment: there was a typo (1 space too much), corrected it ! Working now?

Comment: Thanks your help again Dave, just tried again, the home page is working but all the other pages are loaded with a "not found" error.

Comment: Still not working properly.. don't know why.. Is there anything in regards to drupal 7's setting? Basically I didn't change anything in that file except the $base_url;

Comment: can you clarify in the htaccess content that you gave, is 'domain' the name of the domain, or the name of the subfolder? or do you want to use the same subfolder name as your domain name? Does it work when you put my code in front of the existing code? Or does it work when you comment (#) the first 3 existing lines (not taking into account the RewriteEngine-line)

Comment: In my specific case, "domain" is the name of the domain and also is the same as the "subfolder" name; I tried put your code in front of the existing, it didn't work; I tried comment (#) the first 3 existing lines, but without your code, it showed without css and most of the images are not loading properly; I tried comment (#) the first 3 existing lines, and insert your code just below the RewriteEngine line, still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62261/discussion-between-daveg-and-hunteryxx).